# Highchart, SQL and Laravel

Tags: sql-server, highcharts, laravel-5

I have got the high chart to work on a page in Laravel 5.2.

I can successfully pull data from the SQL database

```
<?php $sales = DB::table('SalesData')
    ->select('Amount')
    ->where('SalesYear','2016')
    ->groupby('MonthShortName')
    ->get()
?>
```

Question is two fold.

**1. How do I get that variable in the highchart**

```
            name: 'Sales',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 2,
            data: [<?php $sales?>],
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            dashStyle: 'shortdot',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' R\'s'
            }
```

**2. How do I select the column AMOUNT from the sql table and SUM the amount at the same time as per the query above.**

Answer (score 0):

1) I advice you to use the json_encode() in PHP file, then in JS use $.getJSON() to load file. Next step is set a reference to name of field in Highcharts.

As a result you keep transparency in your code.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for the feedback. Are there any tutorials on JSON and Laravel combination? Or is that a silly question ;-)

Comment: Being honest Im not familiar with the Laravel